# jQuery select onchange if not option selected

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a select field for users to add a T-shirt to their order. The options look like:

- No tshirt (`value="no"`)
- Small (`value="S"`)
- Medium (`value="M"`)
  ...etc.

I currently have my JS set up as:

```
$("select[name='tshirtsize']").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "no"){
        // subtract $15 from subtotal
    } else {
        // add $15 to subtotal
    }
});
```

However, if a user selects one shirt size and then changes to a different shirt size, it seems to add another shirt to their cart instead of replacing the first one. This makes sense, as it *should* operate this way; however, I don't want it to.

What I'm trying to do is add $15 to the user subtotal ONLY IF they are changing from `value="no"` to `value="shirt-size-here"`, not between shirt sizes.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a variable that defines if you were already on no

```
var none_selected = true; //change this based on whatever the default is
$("select[name='tshirtsize']").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "no"){
        // subtract $15 from subtotal
        none_selected = true;
    } else if (none_selected) {
        // add $15 to subtotal
        none_selected = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable to store the selected choice like this :

```
tmpSelection = "no";
$("select[name='tshirtsize']").change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == "no"){
      // subtract $15 from subtotal
   } 
   else if(tmpSelection != "no" && $(this).val() != "no") {
    // add $15 to subtotal
   }
   tmpSelection = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var base_price = X;
$("select[name='tshirtsize']").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() != "no"){
        var new_price = base_price + Y;
        // update price to show user.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to me seems to be to store a hasTShirt boolean outside of the click event. Another option would be looking at grabbing the previous value of the selector on the selector.select() event, but it would only involve storing the same amount of data...

Example:

```
var hasTshirt = 0; //0 = false, 1 = true    
  $("select[name='tshirtsize']").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "no" && hasTshirt == 1){
         hasTshirt = 0;
        // subtract $15 from subtotal
    } else if (hasTshirt == 0){
        hasTshirt = 1;
        // add $15 to subtotal
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a variable specific to the price of THIS product, no matter what the variation (size/color/etc) is.

Instead of manipulating the total directly, manipulate the product-specific price, then add that to the total.

```
$("select[name='tshirtsize']").change(function(){

    var price;

    if($(this).val() == "no"){
        shirtPrice = 0;
    } else {
        shirtPrice = 15;
    }

    var total = getTotal(); // Define these yourself
    setTotal(shirtPrice); // Define these yourself

});
```